# How to use a case statement in mysql function

Tags: mariadb, mysql-function

In know MySQL (MariaDB) functions and the case statement but how to combine the two?
I'm implementing a TO_STR translate function where I don't want to pollute the database with addtional tables. This is what I tried:

```
CREATE FUNCTION CODE_TO_STR(CODE CHAR(4)) RETURNS VARCHAR(50) AS
BEGIN
RETURN SELECT
  CASE CODE
  WHEN '1' THEN 'Code is one'
  WHEN '2' THEN 'Code is two'
  ELSE CODE
  END;
END;
```

which gives an  1064 error.

EDIT: corrected the error RETURN->RETURNS

EDIT:
`Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT CASE CODE WHEN '1' THEN 'Code is one' WHEN '2' THEN 'Code is two...' at line 3 0.000 sec`

Comment: Please always specify the entire error message. Error 1061 is used for duplicate key error. Also check the documentation for correct function syntax: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-function/

Comment: Thanks yeah. PhpMyAdmin does not show the error message

Comment: But I updated the quetions

Answer (score 2):

(@theking2 gives a straightforward answer.  I am giving a more general answer.)

- The `RETURN` of a `FUNCTION` needs an "expression".
- A `SELECT` returning a single value can be either a "statement" or an "expression".  But...
- When used as "expression", a `SELECT` statement must be surrounded by parentheses.

Comment: RETURN should result in a syntax error,  `RETURNS` is the keyword.

Comment: `RETURNS` is in the beginning of the function declaration to give the datatype; `RETURN` is the statement that terminates the body and provides the value.

Comment: Thanks, well spotted I have updated the question

Answer (score 1):

The `SELECT` is superfluous. the correct `CREATE` should be:

```sql
DELIMITER @@
CREATE FUNCTION CODE_TO_STR(CODE CHAR(4)) RETURNS VARCHAR(50)
BEGIN
RETURN
  CASE CODE
  WHEN '1' THEN 'Code is one'
  WHEN '2' THEN 'Code is two'
  ELSE CODE
  END;
END@@
```